# My Print statement gives me different result each time used inside and outside a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if-statement, conditional-statements

> Let’s learn about list comprehensions! You are given three integers x, y and z representing the dimensions of a cuboid along with an integer n. Print a list of all possible coordinates given by (i, j, k) on a 3D grid where the sum of i + j + k is not equal to n. Here, 0 <= i <= x; 0 <= j <= y; 0 <= k <= z. Please use list comprehensions rather than multiple loops, as a learning exercise.

Initial Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input("Enter x "))
    y = int(input("Enter y "))
    z = int(input("Enter z "))
    n = int(input("Enter n "))
    output=[]
    matric=[]
    for i in range(x+1):
        for j in range(y+1):
            for k in range(z+1):
                if i+j+k!=n:
                    matric=[i,j,k]
                    print(output.append(matric))
```

Output:

```
Enter x 1
Enter y 1
Enter z 1
Enter n 2
None
None
None
None
None
```

Rectified Code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = int(input("Enter x "))
    y = int(input("Enter y "))
    z = int(input("Enter z "))
    n = int(input("Enter n "))
    output=[]
    matric=[]
    for i in range(x+1):
        for j in range(y+1):
            for k in range(z+1):
                if i+j+k!=n:
                    matric=[i,j,k]
                    output.append(matric)
    print(output)
```

Output:

```
Enter x 1
Enter y 1
Enter z 1
Enter n 2
[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Please let me understand why do I get different outputs when the task provided is the same

Answer (score 0):

In the first loop, you are printing output.append(matrix) instead of the matrix value. See carefully! output.append(x) does not return anything so you see those None values. You are actually trying to print the output of a method, which has None as it's return value...
In the second loop, you are printing the real matrix.

I hope this solved your query.